# Power Pi from 7A power supply

Tags: power, usb-power

I would like to buy [this](http://www.arlight.ru/catalog/v-zashchitnom-kozhukhe-366/blok-pitaniya-aps-35-5-5v-7a-35w-016883.html) 7A power supply to charge my phones, power raspberry pi and externally power (like [this](http://www.computeraudiophile.com/attachments/f6-dac-digital-analog-conversion/5123d1365495567-modding-universal-serial-bus-industry-standard-cables-connectors-and-communications-protocols-between-computers-and-electronic-devices-cable-power-digital-analogue-converter-external-power-supply-unit-usbcablediag.jpg)) simple USB hub connected to pi.

Is this supply suitable for powering pi?

Should I worry about 5.75-6.75V over voltage threshold?

How to know amount of current, my hub can handle?

Can USB devices, phones or pi be hurt, by such current or they guaranteed to draw only amount they can handle?

Comment: You need to find out what 5.75-6.75 over voltage protection actually means.  USB (1&2) devices expect 4.75-5.25 volts.  The Pi will probably die if 6 volts is reached.

Comment: Link to PDF on www.arlight.ru returns `СТРАНИЦА НЕ НАЙДЕНА` which Google translates to `Page not found`

Comment: Yesterday I just received an [Asus Zenpower 10050mah accumulator](http://www.emag.ro/acumulator-extern-universal-asus-zenpower-10050mah-negru-90ac00p0-bbt001/pd/DYC5YYBBM/)–this is not spam but just want to say that I'm happy with this and works really nice with the pi. It outputs constant 5V voltage. I recommend. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău Thanks, but I'm looking for stationary solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not worry about the current a power supply can provide. The current that actually flows is depending on the load (more profanely spoken: the resistance of the load and the voltage applied determine the current that flows). So as long as the power supply can support as much current as is needed you're fine.

The output voltage 5 V with a 5% tolerance, as listed in the datasheet, is perfectly ok. It is within the limits of USB specifications and fine for the Pi too. This value should be of relevance over what's listed in the over voltage protection section of the datasheet.

Answer (score -1):

2 Amps and 5v are required. If the supply can serve more than 2 amps, nothing happends. However no more than 5v can be sent to the raspberry or it will burn.